# Changing fonts that are in Latex

Tags: fonts, luatex, gregorio

I've encountered a bit of a problem. Namely, I'm using `gregorio` to typeset chant notation, but I'm doing it for cistercian chant notation.

There is one slight issue with that. Namely, the dagger that denotes flexa and is a part of the `greextra` font, would have to be replaced with cistercian flexa, which can, afaik, only be found in `meinradb` font.

I've tried copying it from one font to another, using FontForge, and I copied it successfully to `greextra.sfd` file found in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/gregoriotex` and to `greextra.ttf` found in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/gregoriotex` ...

I've then tried rebuilding the pdf file using texworks, yet the notation remains unchanged. The glyph that was changed is still the same. Any suggestions on solving this?

Comment: Changing the font files directly should not be done. If you've built the fonts rename them and put them in another tex-root. Then update FNDB and maps.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. So, it would be possible to simply import meinradb font, create a command and simple use that for the flexa when I need it? (Sorry, am newbie.)

Comment: I am actually using LuaLaTex (hence the luatex tag ...). Thanks. Will check it out. Hopefully there are some good guides. :D

Comment: Using LuaLaTeX you do not have to do those complicated things. You just need the TTF name of your font and could include it using `\def\dagger{\fontspec{yourfilehere}<DAGGER SYMBOL>}` with the unicode symbol.

Comment: Perfect. This works. Mind writing is as an answer, so I can pick it as a solution, or should I just mark the question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are in LuaLaTeX you could simply utilize `fontspec`'s facilities for font management. A general purpose version for replacing any specific symbol command (here `\dagger`) would be:

```
\def\dagger{{\fontspec{yourfontfilehere}<SYMBOL HERE>}}
```

This will use the specified font (name or file) to print the unicode character in the group. Hence you need to replace `<SYMBOL HERE>` by the unicode character you have replaced in your modified font.

---

As @egreg suggested it would be a good idea to define a new font family for the use in `\dagger` like

```
\newfontfamily\daggerfont{nameorfile}
\def\dagger{{\daggerfont\symbol{"2020}}}
```

Comment: After using `\dagger` everything will be typeset in the changed font; you're forgetting a pair of braces. It's also better not to use `\fontspec`: define `\newfontfamily{\myfontfordagger}{SomeFont}` and `\renewcommand{\dagger}{{\myfontfordagger\symbol{"2020}}}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I've forgotten the braces. Your suggestion was added.